# Como sincronizar duas TListViews?

Tags: delphi, listview

Estou trabalhando em um *App* para *Android* utilizando o *Delphi XE8* e eu preciso sincronizar duas *ListViews* para que quando o usuário baixar uma, a outra baixe junto.

Como eu faço isso no *Delphi*?

Comment: Você guarda essas informações em um FDMemTable?... usa os Bindigs para fazer a ligação para que aparece essas informações no ListView?... tente ser mais claro na hora de fazer a pergunta.

Comment: Você não precisa saber disso para saber como sincronizar duas list views. Passei as informações necessárias.

EDIT: Para deixar claro, eu me referia a sincronizar a posição atual, o Y, o Index, e não dados entre as duas. Talvez nisso eu não tenha sido claro.

Comment: Desculpe, estou tentando te ajudar e a reformular melhor a pergunta, para melhor entendimento e para o fórum.

Comment: Tudo bem :) talvez eu não tenha passado detalhes o suficiente mesmo. Da próxima vez vou tentar ser mais detalhista, quem sabe ajuda melhor os que estão procurando por soluções parecidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se utilizar uma versão superior ao Delphi XE 8, clica no *events* do listview1 e de seguida clica no evento `OnScrollViewChange` e adiciona o seguinte código:

```
Listview2.ScrollViewPos := Listview1.ScrollViewPos;
```

Feito isso a partir deste momento sempre que mexer na lista 1 a lista 2 fará *scrool* para a mesma localização que a primeira.